# Can I repeat only in filter but keeping it to one element?

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am wondering if I can use ng-repeat over an array but keeping it to 1 element but to show the repeated objects inside an attribute instead.

This is my current code:

```
 <span ng-if='locations.length >= 2'>Several places</span>
 <span ng-if='locations.length <= 1' ng-repeat="location in locations">{{location.city}}</span>
```

What I want to do now is if the `locations.length` is 2 or more elements I want this to show instead:

```
<span title='New York, Dallas, Los Angeles'>Several places</span>
```

I want my locations  to repeat only inside the title attribute.
Now when I do like this:

```
<span ng-if='locations.length >= 2' ng-repeat="location in locations" title="{{location.city + ', '}}">Several pl..</span>
```

I get the following code which isnt wrong because that is what I've coded:

```
<span title="New York ,">Several places</span>
<span title="Dallas ,">Several places</span>
<span title="Los Angeles ,">Several places</span>
```

But it is not what I want my code to do, but I cannot really find how to do what I want to do. How can I achieve that my items in locations gets repeated only inside the title attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a method in your controller that concatenates all city names as below

```
$scope.concatAllCityNames = function(locations) {
    var allCityNames = "";
    angular.forEach(locations, function(location ,index){
        allCityNames =  allCityNames + location.city;
        if(index < locations.length-1) {
          allCityNames =  allCityNames + ", ";
        }
    });
   return allCityNames;
}
```

call this method using AngularJS expression from `title` attribute as below

```
<span ng-if='locations.length >= 2' title="{{concatAllCityNames(locations)}}" >Several places</span>
```

Alternatively you can concatenate all city names in a $scope variable while retrieving locations and access it from title attribute as below

```
<span ng-if='locations.length >= 2' title="{{allCityNames}}" >Several places</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to create a variable in the controller (since you didn't say anything about `locations` I made an assumption:

```
var locations = [
  {city: 'New York'}, 
  {city: 'Dallas'}, 
  {city: 'Los Angeles'}
]

$scope.locationsTitle = locations.map(obj => obj.city).toString(); // 'New York,Dallas,Los Angeles'
```

Now you can use `locationsTitle` in the view to have what you asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a variety of answers, you could also achieve what you're after with a directive. This example will make it flexible so that you can pass any collection of objects to the directive and specify which property on the objects to use for the title.

*directive*

```
.directive('elementWithTitle', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            titleItems: '=',
            titleItemProperty: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var title = '';
            angular.forEach(scope.titleItems, function(item){
                title += item[scope.titleItemProperty] + ', ';
            });
            // strip off last ,
            title = title.substring(0, title.length - 2);
            element.attr('title', title);
        }
    }
})
```

*html*

```
<span ng-if="locations.length >= 2" element-with-title title-items="locations" title-item-property="city">Several Places</span>
```